# Ejecutar acción después del pago en WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy intentando que el usuario solamente pueda acceder a escribir y publicar posts **después** de haber comprado un artículo en WooCommerce, **no antes de ello**.

He estado investigando mucho y preguntando y creo que estoy cerca, pero el código no da error, aunque tampoco hace lo que quiero. Por cierto, el código lo estoy escribiendo en functions.php. Supongo que ese será el sitio correcto.

No sé muy bien cómo hacerlo porque tengo pocos conocimientos de programación y soy nuevo en WordPress. ¿Por qué puede estar fallando y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Éste es el código:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );

function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    if( empty($user) ){
        echo "La variable está vacía"; 
    }else{ 
        $user->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
    } 
}
```

Comment: que error te sale??

Comment: No sale ningún error. Simplemente no hace nada. El resultado que espero que salga es que después de finalizar la compra aparezca el botón de publicar (por haber añadido la capacidad) en vez del de enviar para revisión.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿tienes algún framework instalado tales como Thesis o Genesis? Creo que lo que te falta es incluir esa función en la parte que quieres que aparezca (página o post específico, o todos los que tengan una determinada plantilla). Se puede hacer mediante un `hook` o mediante `shortcodes`

Comment: Gracias, Cedano. Pues que yo sepa no tengo ningún framework instalado. La verdad es que pensé que era suficiente con incluir ese código en el archivo functions.php ¿Es imprescindible usar un framework para lo que deseo hacer?

Comment: Si no mencionas con @a-cedano no adivino que has respondido, no me notifica nada. Un framework no es obligatorio, pero cuando personalizas algo debes indicar luego **dónde** quieres que aparezca eso que has personalizado. Con un framework (para mí) es más fácil, y usando `functions.php` nunca lo he hecho, aunque tampoco debe ser complicado. Creo que sería bueno leer algo sobre como agregar contenido personalizado en WP mediante `functions.php`, supongo que es como en los frameworks, mediante `hooks` o mediante `shortcodes` que escribes donde quieras que sea mostrado el contenido.

Comment: Gracias @a-cedano, no sabía cómo mencionar. Investigaré sobre los frameworks. Había oído hablar de ellos pero no sabía muy bien lo que era ni los había usado. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegá esta función en `functions.php` y dentro del array `$products` escribí el ID de el o los productos contra los cuales querés chequear el pago:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );

function so_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $products = array('22', '23');

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && in_array( $item['product_id'], $products ) ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );
            $user->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
        }
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos es chequear que alguno de los productos del array esté en el carrito para, una vez que se concreta el pago, añadir la capability al usuario que compró y habilitar el botón de *Publicar*.

**Actualización:**

Para hacer que la capability expire luego de *n* cantidad de tiempo, cada vez que demos acceso a un usuario para publicar posts, vamos a guardar en la base de datos un metadato asociado cuya clave es `access_expires` y el valor será la fecha actual (asegurate de tener configurada correctamente la zona horaria en *Ajustes/General*) mas la cantidad de tiempo que queremos que dure la suscripción. En este caso configuré `+5 minutes` en la variable `$date` para probar rápidamente. Otros posibles valores podrían ser `+n days` o `+n months`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );

function so_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $products = array('22', '23');

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && in_array( $item['product_id'], $products ) ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );
            $user->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );

            date_default_timezone_set( get_option('timezone_string') );
            $date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i', strtotime( '+5 minutes' ) );

            update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'access_expires', $date );
        }
    }
}
```

Luego, lo que tenemos que hacer es añadir otro *action hook* para que, cada vez que un usuario se loguee, podamos comparar la fecha de expiración que tiene su suscripción contra la fecha actual. Si es menor o igual significa que la suscripción expiró, entonces revocamos la capability y eliminamos el metadato asociado que habíamos creado previamente:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_user_access' );

function check_user_access( $user_login, $user = null ) {
    if ( !$user ) {
        $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
    }

    if ( !$user ) {
        return;
    }

    $access_expires = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'access_expires', true );

    if ( strtotime( $access_expires ) <= strtotime( current_time( 'Y-m-d H:i' ) ) ) {
        $user->remove_cap( 'publish_posts' );
        delete_user_meta( $user->ID, 'access_expires' );
    }
}
```

En este caso la capability se otorga sólo por 5 minutos. Es decir que, pasado ese tiempo, cuando vuelvas a loguearte ya no deberías ser capaz de publicar posts.

Seguramente hay soluciones mucho mejores, pero fue lo que se me ocurrió.

Comment: Hola @Lagg3r. Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta elaborada y bien explicada. El problema es que lo he probado y parece que no se activa el botón de publicar. Es muy raro que no funcione porque veo que los códigos son razonables y no devuelven ningún error... empiezo a pensar que el error esté en algo básico que no haya configurado bien... o incluso en el hecho de que estoy simulando la compra al no estar la web activa. ¿Puede ser?

Comment: @Matrix No creo que sea un error de configuración. Yo lo probé en una instalación de WordPress nueva en mi localhost. Creé un usuario con el rol _Colaborador_ y un cupón con el 100% de descuento para poder realizar la compra, y funcionó. ¿Estás seguro de que pusiste correctamente el ID del producto en el array `$products`?

Comment: Perfecto!! Ahora sí funcionó! Eres un genio!! Agregué un nuevo producto con otro ID e hice lo del cupón con el 100% de descuento y no hubo ningún problema! Quizá no funcionaba porque la compra era simulada y no terminaba de pagar el producto, o algo así, no sé. Muchísimas gracias!! Me has ayudado muchísimo!

Comment: Ahora me surge la duda de si se puede hacer que se pueda añadir esta capacidad solo temporalmente, es decir, anularla después "x" días o meses. ¿Puedes darme alguna idea? Gracias de nuevo. He investigado en php y hay funciones como por ejemplo "sleep" o "time_sleep_until", pero no sé si voy por buen camino. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: @Matrix Ahí actualicé mi respuesta para añadir esa posibilidad. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Perfectísimo! Funcionó a la primera, muchísimas gracias. Respuesta eficiente, rápida y muy bien explicada. Eres un genio!